# Using GtkD on Linux, how do i statically link the compiled library?

Tags: static-libraries, d, ubuntu-12.04, gtkd

This is kind of linked to this question here: [GtkD (the Gtk+bindings for the D language) why compile it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905212/gtkd-the-gtkbindings-for-the-d-language-why-compile-it)

I'm using GtkD with the D programming language on Ubuntu 12.04 and i'm stuck trying to statically link the compiled libs with my program. Once GtkD is compiled there are three libraries

1. libgtkd.a
2. libgtkdgl.a
3. libgtkdsv.a

After doing `make install` these are placed into the `/usr/local/lib/` folder and the GtkD source is placed inside the `/usr/local/includes/d/` folder. I've also compiled the source to `*.di` files and placed them in the relevant folders in `/usr/local/includes/d/` as the make script doesn't do this by default.

Here's the source i want to compile.

```
pragma(lib, "/usr/local/lib/libgtkd.a");

import gtk.MainWindow;
import gtk.Label;
import gtk.Main;

void main(string[] args)
{
    Main.init(args);
    MainWindow win = new MainWindow("Hello World!");
    win.setDefaultSize(200, 100);
    win.add(new Label("Hello World"));
    win.showAll();
    Main.run();
}
```

Here's the compiler command i use:

```
rdmd -L-ldl hello_world.d
```

Here's the errors:

```
/usr/local/lib/libgtkd.a(Loader.o): In function `_D4gtkc6Loader12pLoadLibraryFAyaE4gtkc6Loader4RTLDZPv':
src/gtkc/Loader.d:(.text._D4gtkc6Loader12pLoadLibraryFAyaE4gtkc6Loader4RTLDZPv+0x28): undefined reference to `dlopen'
src/gtkc/Loader.d:(.text._D4gtkc6Loader12pLoadLibraryFAyaE4gtkc6Loader4RTLDZPv+0x31): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/lib/libgtkd.a(Loader.o): In function `_D4gtkc6Loader10pGetSymbolFPvAyaZPv':
src/gtkc/Loader.d:(.text._D4gtkc6Loader10pGetSymbolFPvAyaZPv+0x23): undefined reference to `dlsym'
src/gtkc/Loader.d:(.text._D4gtkc6Loader10pGetSymbolFPvAyaZPv+0x2c): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/lib/libgtkd.a(Loader.o): In function `_D4gtkc6Loader14pUnloadLibraryFPvZi':
src/gtkc/Loader.d:(.text._D4gtkc6Loader14pUnloadLibraryFPvZi+0x9): undefined reference to `dlclose'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
--- errorlevel 1

shell returned 1
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong? It looks like an ld error but that's linked right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of arguments matters with **ld**, the linker. In general you should place dependencies *after* the code/library which depends on them. So I'd rewrite your pragmas like so:

```
pragma(lib, "gtkd"); // let ld find it in your path
pragma(lib, "dl");   // gtkd depends on dl, so link it after
```

Now try compiling with:

```
dmd hello_world.d
```

Comment: One question though, how does the string 'gtkd' refer to the file 'libgtkd.a'?

Comment: The linker on your system knows hows to translate it. On linux it prepends a "lib" and appends a ".so".  On Windows, it does the appropriate thing, whatever that is. So it's good practice not to make your linking system-specific.

Answer (score 0):

you pass it along in the arguments dmd knows that they need to be passed to the linker

```
rdmd libgtkd.a libgtkdgl.a libgtkdsv.a -L-ldl hello_world.d
```